# How to make 2D arrays with numpy while preserving inheritance

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Polygon class that uses a 2d ndarray for storing it's points. Every point in the class is an instance of a Vector class, this Vector class inherits numpy's ndarray. Am currently using numpy.vstack to append points, but the problem is that my vector instances are converted to their parent class, numpy.ndarray.

```
import numpy as np


class Vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        arr = np.asarray([args[0], args[1], args[2]]).view(cls)
        arr = arr.astype('float64')
        return arr


class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = np.array([]).reshape(0, 3)

    def append_point(self, point):
        self.points = np.vstack([self.points, point])


poly = Polygon()
vec1 = Vector(1, 2, 3)
print(type(vec1))  # output: <class '__main__.Vector'>

poly.append_point(vec1)

print(poly.points)  # output: [[1. 2. 3.]]
print(type(poly.points[0]))  # output: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to override the `__array_function__` method if you want to preserve the subclass:

```
class Vector(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        arr = np.asarray([args[0], args[1], args[2]]).view(cls)
        arr = arr.astype('float64')
        return arr

    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
         x,y = args[0]
         return func([x.view(np.ndarray), y.view(np.ndarray)], **kwargs).view(Vector)
```

This will give

```
poly = Polygon()
vec1 = Vector(1, 2, 3)    # Vector([1., 2., 3.])

poly.append_point(vec1)

poly.points    # Vector([[1., 2., 3.]])
poly.points[0]    # Vector([1., 2., 3.])
```

Any function you call using `Vector` will be intercepted by `__array_function__` (except ufuncs). Although this works for your specific case you will need to modify it to make it more general for any kind of inputs.

Comment: This depends on the your context of usage. Casting an ndarray by using ```view``` is very cheap. On the other hand, using ```vstack``` for every point in ```Polygon``` is quite expensive, considering that you are essentially making a copy each time. Wouldn't it be better to allocate the number of ```Vector```'s beforehand? You could simply do ```polygon = np.empty(N, 3)``` for ```N``` Vectors in a polygon?

Comment: that's the problem, I don't really know how many points i'll end up with. And is there a way to cast only the inner arrays(Vectors) into Vector class.